# Continue a hard Loopy/Slitherlink puzzle without brute-force

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, slitherlink

This is a classic Slitherlink puzzle from [Simon Tatham's Portable Puzzle puzzle collection](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/puzzles/js/loopy.html#10x10t0dh%23247243936692627). I was stuck at the position shown for quite a while until I found a way to continue by logical deduction. I found the deduction quite nice so I thought I would share it here. Or maybe I just overlooked something much simpler. Either way, how do you solve this Slitherlink without any major brute forcing?

[image]

Rules are as follows: Form a single closed loop out of the grid edges, in such a way that every numbered square has exactly that many of its edges included in the loop.

Click on a grid edge to mark it as part of the loop (black), and again to return to marking it as undecided (yellow). Right-click on a grid edge to mark it as definitely not part of the loop (faint grey), and again to mark it as undecided again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Look at the red circle pictured below.

> [image]
>
>  Such a circle must cross the slitherlink solution an even number of times (see below), so the four yellow edges the red circle intersects with must contain 0, 2, or 4 edges from the solution. We know there is exactly one crossing among the two yellow edges of the box marked with a 2 at the bottom left of the red circle. Therefore there must be exactly one crossing among the two yellow edges of the box with a 1. The other two sides of the 1 can therefore be eliminated, indicated by the red crosses.
>
>  After that, further deductions can be made around  the boxes in the third column marked 2,1,3.
>
>  Here I used a circle, but this technique can be used with a closed loop of any shape that separates the grid into two regions (the region inside the loop, and the region outside). The solution will have to cross between the two regions an even number of times because the solution is itself also a closed loop. If a path crosses between the regions an odd number of times, then it would start in one region and end in the other, which means it cannot close into a loop.
>  Often you can use a curve that cuts the grid into two regions, but that can still be thought of as a closed loop if you connect the two ends of the curve together outside the grid.

Comment: Nice, that is the same area where I found something but I think your argument is simpler than mine.

Comment: @quarague I assume your solution involves considering the number that can be on the empty cell there? (in this case, only 1 or 3, and either case forces the X in this answer) When I used that for the first time I also felt really good, haha.

Comment: @justhalf I looked at the two 1s around the circled area. If they are not connected through a horizontal or vertical line, then the 2 at the right bottom of them would need the bottom and right line which would contracdict the 2 to the right bottom of that 2. Hence these two 1s are connected and I can remove their outer edges. This forces two of the 3s around it and from there on it is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Also note that the entire block on the top right has two different solutions depending on whether the 3 in the top center connects at the bottom or top so you can't continue over there.

Comment: The implication is pretty big. Thanks, adding that technique to my repertoir. Often I can deduce it's in the middle, but never thought that means the outer edges can be crossed out.

Comment: @Christoph The four yellow edges referred to are those that cross the circle, not the contained square. (I found this confusing when I first read it.)

Comment: "Here I used a circle, but this technique can be used with a closed loop of any shape that separates the grid into two regions."

Just so I'm understanding this correctly, the "two regions" that you mention here are the area of the puzzle inside the circle and the area of the puzzle outside of the circle, correct?

Comment: @LeppyR64 Exactly. In practice you can also use a curve that cuts the grid in two, but that can still be thought of as a closed loop if you connect the two ends of the curve together outside the grid.

Comment: It seems so obvious now.  Thanks for the succinct summary.

Comment: Yep, that's one of the nice strategies. Probably a more advanced one, but useful nonetheless!

Answer (score 7):

I realize that the intended solution has already been revealed in a comment, but since I also discovered it and it has not been described in detail in an answer, I thought I might as well add it.

Have a look at

> these connected 1s here: 
>  [image: initial configuration]

If

> the 1s are connected like that, there are only two "configurations" to solve them. It's relatively easy to show by just adding any edge of one of the 1s to the loop and crossing out the now impossible ones. Doing this once for every edge of one of the 1s reveals the following two configurations.

Either

> the inner edges are part or the loop, like that: 
>  [image: inner edges are part of the loop]

or

> the outer edges are part of the loop, like that: 
>  [image: outer edged are part of the loop]

Obviously the second case

> solves the two surrounding 2s. However this leads to an immediate contradiction, as the solution for the bottom right 2 leaves the 2 next to it without a solution: 
>  [image: invalid solution]

Hence we must

> continue with the first configuration, which directly solves the two bordering 3s for us. 
>  [image]

From there on it's more or less straight forward to the solution:

> [image: solution]

Answer (score 5):

Similar location, but different reasoning path:

> [image]
>  If the 3 cell has a top edge, the 2 on its top right will have the blue edges forced, but it can't continue towards top left, since all edges are blocked.
>  Therefore the 3 cell has a left edge instead.
>  Though not sure how helpful this would be for future steps. At the very least, it forces the 2 cell below it to have bottom edge. But a next step is a next step :)